# How use Bundler Build Feature Flags in Vue 3.0 with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, bundler, vuejs3

Vue 3.0 (now stable) has an undocumented feature [Bundler Build Feature Flags](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/tree/master/packages/vue#bundler-build-feature-flags):

> Starting with 3.0.0-rc.3, esm-bundler builds now exposes global
> feature flags that can be overwritten at compile time:
>
> **VUE_OPTIONS_API** (enable/disable Options API support, default: true)
>
> **VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS** (enable/disable devtools support in production, default: false)
>
> The build will work without configuring these flags,
> however it is strongly recommended to properly configure them in order
> to get proper tree-shaking in the final bundle. To configure these
> flags:
>
> webpack: use DefinePlugin
>
> Rollup: use @rollup/plugin-replace
>
> Vite: configured by default, but can be overwritten using the define option
>
> Note: the replacement value must be boolean literals and cannot be
> strings, otherwise the bundler/minifier will not be able to properly
> evaluate the conditions.

**How to actually configure this build flag using vue.config.js and Webpack?**

Tried this way but it doesn't seem to affect the vendors bundle size, or is it supposed to work with production builds only (can't try currently as there is a vue-loader bug breaking my prod builds)?

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      // Define Bundler Build Feature Flags
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        // Drop Options API from bundle
        __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: false,
      }),
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 10):

What you wrote is almost correct. Just delete the `configureWebpack` key and define it like any other plugin.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    // Define Bundler Build Feature Flags
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      // Drop Options API from bundle
      __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: false,
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: The OP provided [`vue.config.js`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js), which uses `configureWebpack`.

Comment: As @tony19 mentioned, [vue.config.js includes configureWebpack](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#configurewebpack) but not `plugins`.

Comment: Isn't `configureWebpack` a vue-cli thing? So just providing `plugins` directly would be the approach for a non-cli config file? https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html Correct me if im wrong please

Comment: @redfox05 Yes, outside of Vue CLI scaffolded projects, you'd use a Webpack config file (e.g., `webpack.config.js`), but the OP indicated that they're using `vue.config.js`, which has its own API to configure the underlying Webpack build. The `configureWebpack` option is passed directly to `webpack`, so `plugins: [/*...*/]` would go under that key. The OP seems to be using the option correctly.

Comment: @tony19 yes thanks, that's what I mean too. I wasn't too clear but I was basically saying the answer these comments are on is wrong, as it relates to non-webpack, not what the OP needs.

Comment: This does not make the errors go away in code sandbox's vue 3 template https://codesandbox.io/s/noisy-vue-3-js-errors-xi3xi

Answer (score 2):

You can get info in this file: `node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/config/base.js`

```
  // feature flags <http://link.vuejs.org/feature-flags>
  webpackConfig
    .plugin('feature-flags')
      .use(require('webpack').DefinePlugin, [{
        __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: 'true',
        __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: 'false'
      }])
```

So config `vue.config.js` like this:

```
module.exports = {
 chainWebpack: config =>
   config.plugin('feature-flags').tap(args => {
     args[0].__VUE_OPTIONS_API__ = JSON.stringify(false)
     return args
   })
}
```

Or:

```
chainWebpack: config =>
  config
    .plugin('feature-flags')
    .use(require('webpack').DefinePlugin, [{
      __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: 'true',
      __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: 'false'
    }])
```